# iPhone Development - Assisted GPS

Tags: iphone, gps, iphone-3gs

What's the deal with iPhone's GPS? I never get a good reading when i'm in my office building, or in my room. What really ticks it! and what doesn't? Please help me understand the assisted GPS science.

Comment: This question is too hard to answer with any amount of usefulness in this forum. You should start at Wikipedia, or if you don't trust that, head to your local book store and check out the engineering section. In short, GPS requires a lock on at least 3 satellites to locate you. This requires line of site and time, so AGPS uses triangulation from cell towers and geo information from your IP and nearby WiFi beacons to place you in the general location until a better fix can be had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the gps tries to pinpoint your position using three methods:
1. Satellite
2. Mobile network
3. Wi-fi networks

So if you don't have a good reading, then probably one or more of these methods cannot be used properly in your area. For instance, satellite will not always work that well in buildings with thick walls and ceilings.

Comment: agps tries to place you by these methods. regular gps only uses satellites.

Answer (score 1):

Assisted GPS means that it may have it's location from different sources than GPS satellites, for instance known wifi hotspots, or GSM masts. However these sources are less accurate the true GPS.

Claus

Answer (score 1):

For the actual GPS in your iphone to get a good position, it has to be in direct sight of the GPS satellites.  It cannot do that inside a building.  So if you are inside you are not going to get the best position from the iphone.  It can give you a position using other methods such as the cell phone network and public wi-fi networks, but these positions aren't as accurate as the real GPS position.

Here is an article that explains the GPS system:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gps

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whose definition of Assisted GPS.

True 'assisted GPS' means the GPS receiver uses a known initial position, from the cell tower location, to bootstrap the GPS position calculations. If you know where you are it's much quicker for the position solution to lock to the signal - that's why GPS take so long to find first fix compared to updating.

Some APIs use assisted GPS as shorthand for alternate location services where if GPS is not available, is disabled, or would use too much battery power it will supply a lower grade position based on cell tower triangulation or other methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers I found in WWDC 2010 – Session 115 - Using Core Location in iOS 4.
Very advised.